# Flask Server-Side Session Expiration

Tags: python, flask, session, flask-session

#### Problem

I need server-side sessions to expire after a given amount of time, but when using flask-sessions the session expiration is prolonged every time the site is refreshed.

#### What I have tried

I have set a lifetime on the sessions, but I can see that the expiry is determined on the client side, and that it is prolonged every time I refresh the site:

```
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION'] = True
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
```

I tried setting it to False which gives the same results.

```
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION'] = False
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
```

How to I ensure that it is the server that determines whether a session has run out? I don't what the user to be able to set up a script that just keeps a session going infinitely!

Comment: I have now fixed the problem :)

Comment: How'd you fix it?

Comment: That was the answer to a deleted comment :) But one way to fix it is simply to save a timedate to your server-side cookie, and then check if it is expired before accessing and endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply ended up adding the session-creation-date to the session store, and then I check the duration between this date and the current date.